# How to handle multiple type of json in one parser class?

Tags: apex, rest-api, json

I am expecting two separate jsons in case of success and failure.

In case of success I get a nested json whereas in failure I get a simple json mentioning status : failed so my class I used to handle success is failing for failure scenario. Can someone please guide here?
Only way I can think in checking the substring of json and validate before parsing but that doesn't seem a good solution.

Updated Jsons: 
**Success:**

```
{
    "Subscriptions": [
        {
            "Subscription": {
                "SAPOrder": "SAP123",
                "RequestType": "New",
                "OrderStatus": "0",
                "Services": [
                    {
                        "Service": [{
                            {
                                "attribute": {
                                    "name": "Resilience",
                                    "value": "Terminated"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "attribute": {
                                    "name": "Number",
                                    "value": "1234"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "attribute": {
                                    "name": "serviceStartDate",
                                    "value": "2018-08-220T02:13:20"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                            {{
                                "attribute": {
                                    "name": "Resilience",
                                    "value": "Terminated"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "attribute": {
                                    "name": "Number",
                                    "value": "1234"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "attribute": {
                                    "name": "serviceStartDate",
                                    "value": "2018-08-220T02:13:20"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Failure:**

```
  {
        "Subscriptions": [
            {
                "Subscription": {
                    "SAPOrder": "SAP123",
                    "RequestType": "New",
                    "OrderStatus": "Failed"
                }
            }
```

**Added Class details:**

```
public class JSON2Apex {

    public class Services {
        public List<Service> Service;
    }

    public List<Subscriptions> Subscriptions;

    public class Attribute {
        public String name;
        public String value;
    }

    public class Subscriptions {
        public Subscription Subscription;
    }

    public class Service {
        public List<Attribute> attribute;
    }

    public class Subscription {
        public String SAPOrder;
        public String RequestType;
        public String OrderStatus;
        public List<Services> Services;
    }


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post apex class as well?

Comment: I have added the class details..

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do anything extra here. As I see in your responses, you still have all attributes in the **error** JSON except for the array of *Services*, which you get only in **success**.

```
"Subscription": {
       "SAPOrder": "SAP123",
       "RequestType": "New",
       "OrderStatus": "0",
}
```

So as long as your wrapper class is in the below format:

```
public class SubscriptionWrapper {
    public Subscription subscription;
    ....
}

public class Subscription {
    public String SAPOrder;
    public String RequestType;
    public String OrderStatus;
    public List<Services> services
}
```

And that you receive the error vs. success on the `OrderStatus` variable, while deserializing your response, you get only what's in the JSON. If the `List<Services>` is present in the JSON in case of success, you get that too when you deserialize, else not.

And then you use the `OrderStatus` value to determine if you received a success vs. error message and use it accordingly as required.

As an example, the below code will work without any issue whether or not you have all the attribtues in the JSON message or not.

```
String jsonStr = '{\"OrderStatus\": \"Success\"}';

Subscription subsc = (Subscription)JSON.deserialize(jsonStr, Subscription.class);
system.debug('Order Status:' + subsc.OrderStatus);
```

Comment: Yes, that's my problem. I can't see orderstatus because parsing will fail due to list<services> not found. Any alternative for that ?

Comment: Have you tried parsing already? I can tell you if the JSON does not contain an attribute in the message, and that when you deserialize the response, your `List<Services>` will just be initialized with `null`.

Comment: And I added a sample "working example". So you should try the parsing first -- it won't fail.

Comment: It fails in this line itself so I can't perform check. Subscription subsc = (Subscription)JSON.deserialize(jsonStr, Subscription.class);

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: expected list of services found "" like that

Comment: You should review your implementation and the JSON to make sure it aligns to your wrapper class. Because you don't have the wrapper class in here, and the one I posted in the example works perfectly fine without the attribute being present in the JSON.

Comment: I got the class from the json2apex.. It works fine when all attributes are there but for this scenario it fails.

Comment: The reason this is happening because json is having "" for services instead of list in case of failure. So I have to either remove that element from json then it worked. What would you suggest? I guess if I am getting "" instead of expected format.. then this will not work and no way to cover this. Please suggest

Comment: The issue is with your JSON. If `Services` is supposed to be an array of values, then if at all it is present in the JSON, then it should be sent as `Services : []` and **not as null**. However in your question, it seemed like that array never is sent in the JSON. But in any case, as long as your JSON sends the data based on its schema, your parsing will absolutely work fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can create virtual class to have status of your request, and after that you can extend this class with another one containing success answer fields. E.g.

```
public virtual class BaseResponse {
    public String status {get; set;}
    public String error {get; set;}
}
```

---

```
public class YourResponse extends BaseResponse {
    public List<String> yourDate {get; set;}
}
```

---

after that you can parse response in the following way:

```
YourResponse response = (YourResponse) JSON.deserialize(body, YourResponse .class);
if(response.status == 'success'){
    // do actions on success
} else if(response.status == 'failed'){
    // whos error message e.g. response.error
}
```

this virual class allows you to create other classes, that also have this success-fail responses

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I have updated the question with jsons. My class fails in case of second json.